# How to determine the faces of an array of points?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry, polyhedra, convex-hulls

Is there a way of determining the faces of any polyhedron?

I have an array of $3$-dimensional points and no information what polyhedron should come out.

Comment: Convex hull perhaps?

Comment: Without further information you cannot determine anything. However, you can assume that the faces do not cross each other, or the connected points are close together (as in 3D models in computer design), or more strongly, the polyhedron is convex.

Comment: I see, thanks for that information. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you try to compute the faces of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your set of points. Otherwise, the given information is not enough.

Algorithmically, you could do this by applying some well-known [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) for higher dimensions.